# indexing into an array with SSE

Tags: c, sse, simd

Suppose I have an array:

```
uint8_t arr[256];
```

and an element

```
__m128i x
```

containing 16 bytes,

```
x_1, x_2, ... x_16
```

I would like to efficiently fill a new `__m128i` element

```
__m128i y
```

with values from `arr` depending on the values in `x`, such that:

```
y_1  = arr[x_1]
y_2  = arr[x_2]
   .
   .
   .
y_16 = arr[x_16]
```

A command to achieve this would essentially be loading a register from a non-contiguous set of memory locations. I have a painfully vague memory of having seen documentation of such a command, but can't find it now.  Does it exist?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Fixed the code formatting; in future, keep in mind that if you want to format a block of text as code you have to indent it with 4 spaces and leave a blank line before it (or just select it and press the `0101` button).

Comment: @Matteo: It's not `101010` anymore. It changed to `{ }`...

Comment: @thkala: uh, I didn't notice, in general I just do CTRL-K or copy-paste from my editor where I can add the 4 spaces pressing TAB (and I can benefit from syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kind of capability in SIMD architectures is known as load/store scatter/gather. Unfortunately SSE does not have it. Future SIMD architectures from Intel may have this - the ill-fated Larrabee processor was one case in point. For now though you will just need to design your data structures in such a way that this kind of functionality is not needed.

Note that you can achieve the equivalent effect by using e.g. _mm_set_epi8:

```
y = _mm_set_epi8(arr[x_16], arr[x_15], arr[x_14], ..., arr[x_1]);
```

although of course this will just generate a bunch of scalar code to load your y vector. This is fine if you are doing this kind of operation outside any performance-critical loops, e.g. as part of initialisation prior to looping, but inside a loop it is likely to be a performance-killer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "Gather/Scatter" is clearly the term I was looking for.  After a brief inspection, it looks like such functionality is available on GPUs.  Any advice along those lines?

Comment: Even on GPUs this can be inefficient, since loading/storing to/from different memory addresses will inevitably mean more bus cycles.

Comment: The `_mm_set_epi8` allows you to perform the load (some hand waiving) into `__m128i`. How do you do a similar store from the `__m128i` to the array elements?

Comment: @jww: there is no convenient or efficient way to do a scattered store with SSE - I would probably just use a union and a loop to perform the stores.