# Dereference pointers in XMM register (gather)

Tags: pointers, sse, simd

If I have some pointer or pointer-like values packed into an SSE or AVX register, is there any particularly efficient way to dereference them, *into* another such register? ("Particularly efficient" meaning "more efficient than just using memory for the values".) Is there *any* way to dereference them all without writing an intermediate copy of the register out to memory?

Edit for clarification: that means, assuming 32-bit pointers and SSE, to index into four arbitrary memory areas at once with the four sections of an XMM register and return four results at once to another register. Or as close to "at once" as possible. (/edit)

Edit2: thanks to PaulR's answer I guess the terminology I'm looking for is "gather", and the question therefore is "what's the best way to implement gather for systems pre-AVX2?".

I assume there isn't an instruction for this since ...well, one doesn't appear to exist as far as I can tell and anyway it doesn't seem to be what SSE is designed for at all.

("Pointer-like value" meaning something like an integer index into an array pretending to be the heap; mechanically very different but conceptually the same thing. If, say, one wanted to use 32-bit or even 16-bit values regardless of the native pointer size, to fit more values in a register.)

---

Two possible reason I can think of why one might want to do this:

- thought it might be interesting to explore using the SSE registers for general-purpose... stuff, perhaps to have four identical 'threads' processing potentially completely unrelated/non-contiguous data, slicing through the registers "vertically" rather than "horizontally" (i.e. instead of the way they were designed to be used).
- to build something like [romcc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romcc) if for some reason (probably not a good one), one didn't want to write anything to memory, and therefore would need more register storage.

This might sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), but it isn't, it's just curiosity/stupidity. I'll go looking for nails once I have my hammer.

Comment: Another way to use this would be in something like converting characters to upper/lower case in bulk. Really any time you need a bulk look-up transform on a buffer, there are lots. BTW, the opposite term to "gather" is "scatter," writing back to those locations. And sadly no where in SSE/AVX does it exist.

Comment: Also see [How to use vindex and scale with _mm_i32gather_epi32 to gather elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50883785/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear, but if you want to dereference vector register elements then the only instructions which might help you here are AVX2's gathered loads, e.g. `_mm256_i32gather_epi32` *et al*. See the AVX2 section of the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html).

```
SYNOPSIS

__m256i _mm256_i32gather_epi32 (int const* base_addr, __m256i vindex, const int scale)
#include "immintrin.h"
Instruction: vpgatherdd ymm, vm32x, ymm
CPUID Flag : AVX2

DESCRIPTION

Gather 32-bit integers from memory using 32-bit indices. 32-bit elements are loaded from addresses starting at base_addr and offset by each 32-bit element in vindex (each index is scaled by the factor in scale). Gathered elements are merged into dst. scale should be 1, 2, 4 or 8.

OPERATION

FOR j := 0 to 7
    i := j*32
    dst[i+31:i] := MEM[base_addr + SignExtend(vindex[i+31:i])*scale]
ENDFOR
dst[MAX:256] := 0
```

Comment: Oooh, thanks! "Gather" is the terminology I was looking for. Knowing that, there seems to be a partial answer to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483828/indexing-into-an-array-with-sse).

Comment: @Leushenko, Paul R is correct here and in the question you linked, he answered both :p. However the question you linked is a couple years old and the solution here didn't exist then. _mm256_i32gather_epi32 and less efficiently for an __m128i value _mm_i32gather_epi32 are the correct intrinsics. However yes they do require AVX2. If you have a small look-up table, say 16 byte-sized elements, or even 256, you can, use the SSSE3 intrinsic _mm_shuffle_epi8 to do a 8-byte look-up, and you can mask out high and low parts and add results after some masking to simulate the 256 byte version.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood this correctly, your title is misleading and you really want to:

- index into the concatenation of all XMM registers
- with an index held in a part of an XMM register

Right?

That's hard. And a little weird, but I'm OK with that.

Assuming crazy tricks are allowed, I propose self-modifying code: (not tested)

```
pextrb eax, xmm?, ?  // question marks are the position of the pointer
mov edx, eax
shr eax, 1
and eax, 0x38
add eax, 0xC0        // C0 makes "hack" put its result in eax
mov [hack+4], al     // xmm{al}
and edx, 15
mov [hack+5], dl     // byte [dl] of xmm reg
call hack
pinsrb xmm?, eax, ?  // put value back somewhere
...
hack:
  db 66 0F 3A 14 00 00  // pextrb ?, ? ,?
  ret
```

As far as I know, you can't do that with full `ymm` registers (yet?). With some more effort, you could extend it to `xmm8`-`xmm15`. It's easily adjustable to other "pointer" sizes and other element sizes.

Comment: Nah, I'd like to index into four arbitrary memory areas at once with the four sections of an XMM register and return four results at once to another register. *However*, +1 for the cool idea (could be useful in the context of the second bullet in a different way).